# Mogrify command modify file names?

Tags: imagemagick, mogrify

Im using mogrifiy command in Ubuntu server 20.04 to make a bulk resize, but i will like to know if the use of this command modify the name of the images. Theres my command

```html
mogrify -resize 600x400 '*.jpg'
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. If you want the results in a new directory called `RESULTS`, you can do `mkdir RESULTS` then `mogrify -path RESULTS -resize 600x400 *.jpg` if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No, it doesn't. If you want the results in a new directory called RESULTS, you can do mkdir RESULTS then mogrify -path RESULTS -resize 600x400 *.jpg if that's what you mean. – Mark Setchell